# cloudformation does not attach the requested path param in api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create api gateway in cloudformation. everything is good except when I specify path param url I can see it in the api gateway created. Here is my cfn code:

```
GetMethod:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
Properties:
  AuthorizationType: NONE
  HttpMethod: GET
  Integration:
    Type: HTTP
    IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
    Uri:
      Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - "http://"
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${project}-${EnvironmentApp}-bn-user-endpoint-url
        - "/users"
        - "/{users}"
    IntegrationResponses:
    - StatusCode: 200
      ResponseParameters:
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
      ResponseTemplates:
        application/json: ''
    RequestTemplates:
      application/json: ''
  RequestParameters:
    method.request.path.users: true
  ResourceId: !Ref UsersPathParam
  RestApiId:
    Ref: RestApi
  MethodResponses:
  - StatusCode: 200
    ResponseParameters:
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
```

If you noticed in the code above I specifically ask for path param called users:

```
RequestParameters:
    method.request.path.users: true
```

Also, you can see the created API gateway that has no path param set in the attached image.
Any ideas?

[image: supporting image[1]]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two `RequestParameters` properties: one belongs to the method and one belongs to the integration. Both the *key and value* serve slightly different purposes, which can understandably create confusion.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-requestparameters) for the method property (emphasis added):

> The request parameters that API Gateway accepts. Specify request parameters as **key-value pairs** (string-to-Boolean mapping), **with a source as the key and a Boolean as the value**. **The Boolean specifies whether a parameter is required.** A source must match the format method.request.location.name, where the location is querystring, path, or header, and name is a valid, unique parameter name.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-requestparameters) for the integration property (emphasis added):

> The request parameters that API Gateway sends with the backend request. Specify request parameters as **key-value pairs** (string-to-string mappings), **with a destination as the key and a source as the value**.
>
> Specify the destination by using the following pattern integration.request.location.name, where location is querystring, path, or header, and name is a valid, unique parameter name.
>
> **The source must be an existing method request parameter or a static value.** You must enclose static values in single quotation marks and pre-encode these values based on their destination in the request.

So the currently accepted answer is technically valid, but would likely result in the static value `true` being sent to the integration parameter instead of the method parameter value being passed to the integration. It is more likely that you want to provide a reference to the method parameter.

So, to explain the keys, the method `RequestParameter` key defines *where to find the value* in the method request and the integration `RequestParameter` key defines *where to place the value* in the integration request. This allows you to map the request parameters to completely different integration parameters if you'd like (e.g. placing a request path parameter into the integration querystring, changing the request parameter named `foo` to the integration parameter named `bar`, etc.)

You also may or may not require the method parameter to exist, so set the method parameter boolean value to `true` or `false` depending on whether you want to enforce that value must be included with the method request:

```
GetMethod:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
    ResourceId: !Ref Resource
    AuthorizationType: NONE
    HttpMethod: GET
    RequestParameters:
      - method.request.path.foo: true|false
    Integration:
      Type: HTTP
      IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
      Uri: https://example.com
      RequestParameters:
        - integration.request.path.foo: method.request.path.foo
```

Comment: Andrew this is extremely helpful. I wish the AWS docs were as clear and concise as this.

Comment: @Andrew yes thank you so much - this was much more detailed and helpful than AWS's documentation on the topic:  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-character-error/

Answer (score 1):

Since it needs to be applied in the "integration request" part of the API, you must prefix the parameter with `integration.` Like so:

```
RequestParameters:
  integration.method.request.path.users: "'true'"
```

Also, notice the single quotes, I had to add those to add string literals there but YMMV.

EDIT: 
It looks like your `RequestParameters` is not indented at the right place. It should be under `Integration:` since it's something you want to add at that level.

EDIT 2: 
I've tested using this method and it worked flawlessly:

```
ProxyMethod:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    ResourceId: !Ref ProxyResource
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
    AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM
    HttpMethod: ANY
    RequestParameters:
      method.request.path.proxy: true
    Integration:
      IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
      Type: HTTP_PROXY
      Uri: !Sub ${BaseUrl}/{proxy}
      RequestParameters:
        integration.request.path.user: "'true'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. When I add integration cfn fails with the error: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: integration.method.request.path.users]

Comment: I have this working somewhere. I’ll update with a more complete answer. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added it like this:Integration:
        Type: HTTP
        RequestParameters:
          integration.method.request.path.users: "'true'"
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET   but still the same error. Did I add it in a way u meant?

Comment: Can you make sure your template follows the same structure as my code exemple? Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Woooow thanx a lot man. this post worths 100000 likes. U are awesome :)